# Remove everything from string after and including XYZ

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

If I have the following string:

```
String test;
test = "bla bla bla XYZ bla bla bla XYZ bla bla bla";
```

How do I remove everything including the first occurance of XYZ from the string.  So I should end up with:

```
test2 = "bla bla bla ";
```

---

**Note:** `bla bla bla` can be anything, the location of `XYZ` is not known beforehand, and the number of `XYZ's` is also not know beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) and [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) methods.

Here an example in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/);

```
string test = "bla bla bla XYZ bla bla bla XYZ bla bla bla";
test.Substring(0, test.IndexOf("XYZ")).Dump();
```

This print

```
bla bla bla
```

Here a <kbd>[**`demonstration`**](http://ideone.com/ufhsjQ)</kbd>.

`IndexOf` gets the index of your first `XYZ` occurance no matter how many `XYZ` you have. `Substring` method gets all characters from `0` index to that index.

*NOTE: The result has a white space at the end but you just can't see here :)*

Comment: You should remove the `Dump` :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It is an _extension method_ in LINQPad. It prints it to Results window. Mostly, I'm working with LINQPad when I try to answer questions in SO. That's why I mentioned in my answer :)

Comment: i know, i just thought it might confuse the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) and [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
String test;
test = "bla bla bla XYZ bla bla bla XYZ bla bla bla";
test.Substring(0, test.IndexOf("XYZ"));
```

<kbd>[**`demo`**](http://ideone.com/8QZ1UI)</kbd>

Comment: He need a white space at the end that's why IndexOf

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
var test = "bla bla bla XYZ bla bla bla XYZ bla bla bla";

var result = test.Split(new [] { "XYZ" },StringSplitOptions.None).First();
```

Comment: +1. Nice one, because it also works correctly when there is no XYZ in the text (nothing is removed).